# SASS - Bootstrap 4 - Error when trying to use 'button-size' mixin

Tags: bootstrap-4, sass, scss-mixins

I'm getting an error when trying to use the **button-size** mixin of Bootstrap 4 (version **4.3.1**)

This is the code of the mixin I'm trying to include (taken from '*\node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_buttons.scss*'):

```
@mixin button-size($padding-y, $padding-x, $font-size, $line-height, $border-radius) {
  padding: $padding-y $padding-x;
  @include font-size($font-size);
  line-height: $line-height;
  // Manually declare to provide an override to the browser default
  @include border-radius($border-radius, 0);
}
```

This is a snippet of Bootstrap Sass code in the node_modules of my project where the mixin is used ('*\node_modules\bootstrap\scss\_buttons.scss*') - mixin is included at line **17**:

```
// stylelint-disable selector-no-qualifying-type

//
// Base styles
//

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: $btn-font-family;
  font-weight: $btn-font-weight;
  color: $body-color;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  user-select: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: $btn-border-width solid transparent;
  @include button-size($btn-padding-y, $btn-padding-x, $btn-font-size, $btn-line-height, $btn-border-radius);
  @include transition($btn-transition);

  @include hover {
    color: $body-color;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  &:focus,
  &.focus {
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: $btn-focus-box-shadow;
  }

  // Disabled comes first so active can properly restyle
  &.disabled,
  &:disabled {
    opacity: $btn-disabled-opacity;
    @include box-shadow(none);
  }

  &:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active,
  &:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active {
    @include box-shadow($btn-active-box-shadow);

    &:focus {
      @include box-shadow($btn-focus-box-shadow, $btn-active-box-shadow);
    }
  }
}
```

This is how I include the mixin in my code:

```
.my-btn {
  // $padding-y: 0.5rem
  // $padding-x: 0.25rem
  // $font-size: 0.875rem
  // $line-height: 1.5
  // $border-radius: 0.25rem
  @include button-size(0.5rem, 0.25rem, 0.875rem, 1.5, 0.25rem);
}
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/styles.scss (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./src/styles.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

undefined
          ^
      Wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) for `border-radius'
      in ***\node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_buttons.scss (line 106, column 12)
```

The error is related to the border-radius argument, but I don't understand why it sees 2 arguments when I'm passing just one.

Comment: I imported the entire Bootstrap in my styles.scss file according to this page from the Bootstrap documentation: getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/theming/#importing

Answer (score 0):

how do you import the mixins?

if you import from `node_modules`, you need at least import 3 scss

- function.scss
- variable.scss
- mixins.scss

Answer (score 0):

The button-size mixin uses another font-size mixin:

```
// Button sizes
@mixin button-size($padding-y, $padding-x, $font-size, $line-height, $border-radius) {
  padding: $padding-y $padding-x;
  @include font-size($font-size);
  line-height: $line-height;
  // Manually declare to provide an override to the browser default
  @include border-radius($border-radius, 0);
}
```

The font-size mixin turns a float into an rem value with a px fallback.

```
// Rem output with px fallback
@mixin font-size($sizeValue: 1) {
    font-size: ($sizeValue * 16) * 1px;
    font-size: $sizeValue * 1rem;
}
```

So you need to remove the units from the 3rd parameter and just add a float for rem without specifying rem.

Comment: I tried to remove rem from the font size, but it's still giving me the same error